# What are the downsides to Table Valued Parameters in Stored Proc?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I have worked with various versions of MS SQL Server including 2000,2005,2008,R2,(Some)Denali. I have never been so excited about a new feature like the Table Valued parameters in stored proc. I do C# development as well and I'm digging TVP, I use it to minimize the number of database calls from my front end app.

Now my real question is what are the downsides to using Table Valued Parameters. Its almost too good to be true.

Please share your thoughts. Plus I dont want to get too deep into using it and have to change.

Comment: None - other than it's only available in SQL Server 2008 and newer....

Comment: This might be of interest to you. http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: They're read only, and a lot of people don't like that. Also Erland's article that Mikael posted has some good info about TVP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I did read about the limitations of ready only and 1000 rows performance, but my understanding is individual round trip to db is more expensive compared to TVP limitations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table Value Parameters have few practical drawbacks.

**Benefits**

- Cached upon frequent use
- Facilitate bulk inserts very efficiently
- Reduce round trips to the server

**Drawbacks:**

- SQL Server does not maintain statistics on the TVP Columns
- Readonly
- Can not be used as the target of "Select Into" or "Insert Exec" statements
- Only available on Sql Server 2008 and above

**References**

- [Table Value Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: Additional drawback is a lack possibility to `alter` definition of the type. If you create it once it remains the same till you drop it, but to drop it you have to drop all objects that has reference to that type, i.e. all stored procedures which uses that type.